# Configure AndroidViewClient and Monkeyrunner on macOSX

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I am trying to install AndroidViewClient but there are a lot of problem. I download it on the github of dtmilano. I am on Mavericks an i am new with python.. I know how to use Monkeyrunner but since I download AndroidViewClient, I am totally lost !

Si followed step by step instructions on the github ! When I'm trying to launch ./dump, I got this message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./tools/dump", line 126, in <module>
vc = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1), **kwargs2)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/androidviewclient-5.6.0- py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 1188, in __init__
adb = ViewClient.__obtainAdbPath()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/androidviewclient-5.6.0-py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 1341, in __obtainAdbPath
raise Exception('adb="%s" is not executable. Did you forget to set ANDROID_HOME in the environment?' % adb)
Exception: adb="adb" is not executable. Did you forget to set ANDROID_HOME in the environment?
```

Here is my environment variable :

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Flo/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk/
ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME=/Users/Flo/Documents/Android/AndroidViewClient-5.1.1/AndroidViewClient/
```

I get my AndroidViewClient folder if I do `cd $ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME`
I can't execute scripts..

When I do this line : `python check-import.py --debug`, I got this :

```
sys.path= ['/Users/Flo/Documents/Android/AndroidViewClient-5.1.1/AndroidViewClient/examples', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/androidviewclient-5.6.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Users/Flo/Documents/Android/AndroidViewClient-5.1.1/AndroidViewClient/src']
OK
```

Can anyone helps me please ? I am on it since two days now and I don't know what I can do. I tried a lot of things. Delete AndroidViewClient / Re-install it but it's always the same result

Answer (score 0):

I understand you install it using

```
$ sudo easy_install --upgrade androidviewclient
```

Then, you should do

```
$ export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Flo/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk/
```

add it to `~/.bash_profile` if you want it to be persistent.

Then you should be able to execute `dump` without problems.
The tools are trying to find `adb` at some know locations or at `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb`. Check to be sure that `adb` is there and is executable.